# Echo each shell script command with a timestamp

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

`set -x` or `set -v` prints every executed command.

How do I get the command printed with the time when the command started executing?

Comment: Wich OS/distribution and version do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in Bash, execution of code after each command can be achieved using the "trap" builtin and the "DEBUG" level.

in bash do: help trap
or refer to bash manual page, and look for the trap section

example:

```
trap 'date' DEBUG
```

This will execute the command "date" juste after each command.

Of course you can format the timestamp as you want, refer to the "date" manual page.

If you want to remove the newline, so that timestamp appears in front of next command, you can do:

```
trap 'echo -n $(date)' DEBUG
```

And to terminate this:

```
trap '' DEBUG
```

You can combine with "set -x" / "set +x"

Answer (score 9):

In Bash, you can use `PS4` - which is used by `set -x` to prefix tracing output.

```
PS4='+ $(date "+%s.%N")\011 '
set -x
...
```

> \011 is the horizontal tab character

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is a perfect solution by any means, but I think it basically accomplishes what you need.  Just wrap the main script in a function and have a separate function to call the time.  I'm sure this could be greatly improved upon to get the exact desired result, but here's what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

tstamp() { date +[%T:%N]; }

yourscript() {
  set -x
  echo hello
  sleep 1
  echo this
  sleep 2
  echo is
  sleep 3
  echo an
  echo example
}

yourscript | while read line; do echo -e "$(tstamp)\t$line"; done
```

The above script outputs the following:

```
+ echo hello
+ sleep 1
[16:17:33:344851100]    hello
+ echo this
+ sleep 2
[16:17:34:352269700]    this
+ echo is
+ sleep 3
[16:17:36:380810900]    is
+ echo an
+ echo example
[16:17:39:392033300]    an
[16:17:39:414361400]    example
```